# Sorting multiple custom post types without a meta key/value pair by sort order

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query-posts, sort

At this current moment. is it possible to sort multiple custom post/page types without a meta key/value?

I'm looking to just sort the posts by page attribute order:

[image]

**What have i done so far? I've created a query like so and no luck**

```
  <?php
  // query for videos in the home page category
  $args = array(
   'post_type' =>array('videos', 'podcasts'), 
   'category_name' => 'Videos on Homepage', 
   'post_per_page' => 4,
   'order' => 'DESC'
   );
  $loop = new WP_Query($args);
  // etc....

  ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

What ended up working is adding the array key, "orderby" and adding menu_order:

```
  <?php
  // query for vidoes in the home page category
  $args = array(
   'post_type' =>array('videos', 'podcasts'), 
   'category_name' => 'Videos on Homepage', 
   'post_per_page' => 4,
   'order' => 'DESC',
   'orderby' => 'menu_order',
   );
  $loop = new WP_Query($args);

  // start loop for first set of videos
  while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
```